# 500 Internal Server Error (trying to upload file)

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I have small app in flask was is hosted on pythonanywhere. When I try uploading a file I get 500 error. I copied the code exactly except for changing the UPLOAD_FOLDER path and ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS. Local(on my computer) all working good but on server not.

[Log error](http://pastebin.com/hWdh4VvB)

[My Code](http://pastebin.com/riq5hKMx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in `UPLOAD_FOLDER` path value.

Your python script complains it can't find the directory you set up for uploads. And since you set up it as:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'upload/'
```

And in docs this variable has absolute path to the directory, I think, if you change `upload/` to

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/absolute/path/to/your/upload/directory/'
```

it would help.